# how to update all rows based on specific date by a single mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql table:

```
=============================
id | vid |    date    | num |
=============================
 1 |  1  | 2017-01-01 |     |
 2 |  1  | 2017-02-20 |     |
 3 |  2  | 2017-02-25 |     |
 4 |  1  | 2017-03-05 |     |
=============================
```

I have to update `num` column in such way that if the date is earliest for the same `vid`, then the num column will be 1, otherwise it will be 2. So, after updating the database/table the table will be:

```
=============================
id | vid |    date    | num |
=============================
 1 |  1  | 2017-01-01 |  1  |
 2 |  1  | 2017-02-20 |  2  |
 3 |  2  | 2017-02-25 |  1  |
 4 |  1  | 2017-03-05 |  2  |
=============================
```

As `2017-01-01` is the earliest date for the `vid=1`, so `num` is `1`. All other rows for `vid=1` therefore are `2`. On the other hand for `vid=2`, num column will be 1 as it is the only one row with `vid=2`.

How can I create a single mysql query, so that it will update the whole table automatically based on the above logic automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is 'yourTable':

```
UPDATE 
    yourTable inner join (select *,IF(date=(select min(date) 
                    from yourTable 
                    where vid=a.vid  
                    group by vid), 1, 2) as actualNum
                 from yourTable a) abc 
    ON yourTable.id = abc.id 
SET yourTable.num = abc.actualNum;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
update mytable as m 
set num = case when date = 
(select min(date) from mytable m2 where m2.id = m.id) 
then 1 else 2 end
```

... i think

or maybe

```
UPDATE m
set num = case when date = 
    (select min(date) from mytable m2 where m2.id = m.id) 
    then 1 else 2 end
FROM mytable m
```

Comment: This solution won't work as you cannot pass the same table in the subquery while doing an update on the table.